# Where does the Wonkavator fly to at the end in Willy Wonka and The Chocolate Factory

Tags: willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

I've always wondered where the Wonkavator flies off to into the clouds. Also, where do they land in the Wonkavator off screen? I don't think they could have landed in Charlie's house to pick up the family because the elevator can only fit 3 people so did they just land to give the family the announcement and then Charlie's family moved into the factory?

Answer (score 9):

What you're looking for is in the sequel [*Charlie and the Great Glass Elevator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_and_the_Great_Glass_Elevator). It picks up immediately where the first book leaves off.

They do indeed go to Charlie's house, and manage to stuff Charlie's entire family into the elevator, including the grandparents' bed! The rest of the book details their misadventures trying to get back to the factory.